# Extracting Keywords from text in R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, text-analysis

I want to extract Insurance services related keywords from text in R. I created keywords list and used common function from `qdap` library.

```
   bag <- bag_o_words(corpus) 
   b <- common(bag,keywords,overlap="all")
```

But the results are just the common words with more than 1 frequency.
I have also used `RKEA` library.

```
keywords <- c("directasia", "directasia.com", "Frank", "frank", "OCBC", "NTUC",
              "NTUC Income", "Frank by OCBC", "customer service", "atm",
              "insurance", "claim", "agent", "premium", "policy", "customer care",
              "customer", "draft", "account", "credit", "savings","debit","ivr",
              "offer", "transacation", "banking", "website", "mobile", "i-safe",
               "customer", "demat", "network", "phone", "interest", "loan",
               "transfer", "deposit",  "otp", "rewards", "redemption")
   tmpdir <- tempfile()
   dir.create(tmpdir)
   model <- file.path(tmpdir, "crudeModel")
   createModel(corpus,keywords,model)
   extractKeywords(corpus, model)
```

However I am getting the following errors

> Error in createModel(corpus, keywords, model) : number of documents and keywords does not match

and

> Error in .jcall(ke, "V", "extractKeyphrases", .jcall(ke,Ljava/util/Hashtable;",  :  java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Bitanshu\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEHu9uA\file14c4160f41c2\crudeModel (The system cannot find the file specified)

The second error is I think because `createModel` is not successful.

Can anyone suggest how to rectify this or an alternative approach?
The text data has been extracted from twitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the **quanteda** package.  I'd suggest getting the GitHub version instead of the CRAN release, since just two days ago I overhauled the `kwic()` function.  Example:

```
> require(quanteda)
> kwic(inaugTexts, "asia")
                                           contextPre keyword                       contextPost
 [1841-Harrison, 8599]        or Egypt and the lesser    Asia would furnish the larger dividend
     [1909-Taft, 1872]     our shores from Europe and    Asia of course reduces the necessity  
 [1925-Coolidge, 2215] differences in both Europe and    Asia . But there is a                 
[1953-Eisenhower, 325]           the earth. Masses of    Asia have awakened to strike off      
    [2013-Obama, 1514] We will support democracy from    Asia to Africa, from the
```

Comment: Which version of R are you using because i get the error :Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘quantedata’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)

Comment: 3.2.2 is the latest R, and that is what the CRAN version of quanteda is built for. But as in my answer, for using kwic() to its fullest, I would suggest installing the latest GitHub version of quanteda from source using: `devtools::install_github("kbenoit/quanteda")`. See https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following format for createModel, even if you are not going to use all sections, they need to be mentioned

createModel(corpus,keywords, model, voc = "none", vocformat = "")